# Set timeout for individual entries in async module of Node js

Tags: node.js, timeout, polling

```
function poll()
{
   async.eachLimit(opt,500,function(entry, callback) {

    request({uri:entry, method: "GET",pool:pool,timeout:15000}, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Yes '+entry);
        }
        else {
            console.log('No '+entry);
        }
        callback();
    });
}, function(err) {
}
```

What I am trying to do is check if a website is up/down. Here I am setting the limit(timeout) as 15 sec. But what happens is it considers this timeout for the entire batch of sites and what I am expecting is that each site should be given a separate timeout of 15 sec. opt is the array which consists of all the urls to be checked.

Comment: What `request` is? Is a nodejs module? Can you point to it?

Comment: Thing is that there are several `request` implementations and it seems an important fact to solve the issue.

Comment: Its a node module (https://github.com/mikeal/request). Sorry forgot to mention that. Also pool is defining the max sockets.